# Integrating spring security with Ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jsf, spring-security, primefaces

So I have a web app that utilises jsf and primefaces for it's front end presentation.

We are using Spring security for the login mechanism and have defined the concurrency as such

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
<concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" 
expired-url="multipleLogins.xhtml" />
</session-management>
```

The problem seems to be when  a user has two logins from different browsers there are certain buttonas that perform ajax actions that do not trigger the redirect. It seems to only be buttons that submit forms or redirect to pages themselves that will recognise the multiple logins actions.

For example, this button

```
<p:commandButton id="retrieve" value="#{msgs.BUTTON_RETRIEVE}"
action="#{removeContactForm.retrieve}" update="@form"/>
```

Which retrieves things from a web service and displays them on a page will not trigger the redirect if there are multiple logins.

```
<p:commandButton id="remove" value="#{msgs.BUTTON_REMOVE}"
action="/pages/confirm/confirmRemove.xhtml" ajax="false" process="@this"          
immediate="true" rendered="#{!empty removeContactManager and   
removeContactManager.contactRolesSuccessful}" />
```

This button will however (as it redirects to another page)

Anyone know a way of making the webapp register those ajax calls as events, without sticking everything ajax based into a new page?

Comment: Does the second button redirect to confirmRemove or multipleLogins?

Comment: If there are multiple logins the second button will redirect correctly to 'multipleLogins'. The first one will not, as it is initialising an ajax call, rather than going to a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the JSFRedirectStrategy written by Ben Simpson for redirecting to a session expired url when the session expires using the session management filter. Source can be found [here](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Spring+Security). 
I think the same can be applied here but we need to remove the namespace configuration and add some beans like this:

```
<http>
  <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
  <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/multipleLogins.xhtml" />
  <!-- this permits redirection to session timeout page from javascript/ajax or http -->
  <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class=
   "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class=
 "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
  <beans:property name="alwaysCreateSession" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="com.examples.JsfRedirectStrategy"/>
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Now, you can check if the request was an ajax request and then send a redirect like this in the JSFRedirectStrategy class:
Here is the code copied from the ICEfaces tutorial.

```
/**
 * This class represents an extension to the way DefaultRedirectStrategy works.
 * This class takes into account if the incoming request causing action by Spring Security
 * requires a "partail-response" xml redirect instead of a response.sendRedirect().
 *
 * @author Ben Simpson ben.simpson@icesoft.com
 */
public class JsfRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private boolean contextRelative;


    /**
     * Redirects the response to the supplied URL.
     * <p>
     * If <tt>contextRelative</tt> is set, the redirect value will be the value after the request context path. Note
     * that this will result in the loss of protocol information (HTTP or HTTPS), so will cause problems if a
     * redirect is being performed to change to HTTPS, for example.
     */
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        String redirectUrl = calculateRedirectUrl(request.getContextPath(), url);
        redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectUrl);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Redirecting to '" + redirectUrl + "'");
        }

        //we should redirect using ajax response if the case warrants
        boolean ajaxRedirect = request.getHeader("faces-request") != null
                && request.getHeader("faces-request").toLowerCase().indexOf("ajax") > -1;

        if(ajaxRedirect) {
            //javax.faces.context.FacesContext ctxt = javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            //ctxt.getExternalContext().redirect(redirectUrl);

            String ajaxRedirectXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<partial-response><redirect url=\""+redirectUrl+"\"></redirect></partial-response>";
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter().write(ajaxRedirectXml);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
        }


    }

    private String calculateRedirectUrl(String contextPath, String url) {
        if (!UrlUtils.isAbsoluteUrl(url)) {
            if (contextRelative) {
                return url;
            } else {
                return contextPath + url;
            }
        }

        // Full URL, including http(s)://

        if (!contextRelative) {
            return url;
        }

        // Calculate the relative URL from the fully qualified URL, minus the scheme and base context.
        url = url.substring(url.indexOf("://") + 3); // strip off scheme
        url = url.substring(url.indexOf(contextPath) + contextPath.length());

        if (url.length() > 1 && url.charAt(0) == '/') {
            url = url.substring(1);
        }

        return url;
    }

    /**
     * If <tt>true</tt>, causes any redirection URLs to be calculated minus the protocol
     * and context path (defaults to <tt>false</tt>).
     */
    public void setContextRelative(boolean useRelativeContext) {
        this.contextRelative = useRelativeContext;
    }
}
```