# JSF 2 + Primefaces 5 + Spring Security How to do an AJAX login

Tags: ajax, spring, primefaces, spring-security, jsf-2.2

I have the following configuration in Spring Security:

```
 http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/admin/**", "/login", "/logout").and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/main.xhtml")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin.xhtml").and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied.xhtml");
```

In a login controller (JSF backing bean) I have:

```
public void doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest)context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/login");
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
```

I am using Primefaces for frontend components.

This is the login form:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
   <p:messages id="errorMessages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" />
   <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username"  />
   <p:inputText id="username"  required="true" label="username" />
   <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
   <p:inputText id="password"  required="true" label="password" />
   <p:commandButton  id="login" value="Login" update="errorMessages"
      action="#{loginController.doLogin}" />
</h:form>
```

The problem is that the previous configuration **forwards** completely the response from Spring Security when trying to log in, so the login doesn't work. For it to work I would need to add **ajax="false"** in the p:commandButton but this would cause the whole page to reload in case of a login failure. Reloading the whole page breaks the user experience, for example, in my case users would need to scroll down to the login form if there's a login error.

How can I configure in either JSF or Spring Security so that I can do an AJAX login? Also, in this process, how could I show authentication failure messages from Spring Security?

Comment: Could you please explain me how the answer in the duplicate question applies here? I am trying to redirect the user after a successful login using AJAX not trying to validate if a session is alive.

Comment: Does it work with plainjsf components?

Comment: @Kukeltje with plain JSF components the page reloads when there's an authentication error. It's analogous to adding ajax="false" to the p:commandButton. What I would like is for the Spring Security login validation to be performed in an AJAX way with JSF so it can work just like any other AJAX validation with Primefaces.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074756/integrating-spring-security-with-ajax-calls and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912485/spring-security-ajax-login? concerning the main problem?

Comment: Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708205/spring-security-authentication-failure-message-without-redirects